# Map object but only if value is true

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to organise data from an API call and am struggling.

```
{
        "level_0": 0,
        "index": 0,
        "site": "CELL_A",
        "time": "2022-09-15T09:00:00Z",
        "cell": "CELL_A_1",
        "kpi_name": "kpi_1",
        "kpi_value": 14729.478515625,
        "anomaly": 0
    },
    {
        "level_0": 1,
        "index": 1,
        "site": "CELL_A",
        "time": "2022-09-15T09:15:00Z",
        "cell": "CELL_A_1",
        "kpi_name": "kpi_1",
        "kpi_value": 25999.1796875,
        "anomaly": 0
    },
    {
        "level_0": 2,
        "index": 2,
        "site": "CELL_A",
        "time": "2022-09-15T09:30:00Z",
        "cell": "CELL_A_1",
        "kpi_name": "kpi_1",
        "kpi_value": 21172.47265625,
        "anomaly": 1
    },
    {
        "level_0": 3,
        "index": 3,
        "site": "CELL_A",
        "time": "2022-09-15T09:00:00Z",
        "cell": "CELL_A_1",
        "kpi_name": "kpi_2",
        "kpi_value": 14729.478515625,
        "anomaly": 0
    },
    {
        "level_0": 4,
        "index": 4,
        "site": "CELL_A",
        "time": "2022-09-15T09:15:00Z",
        "cell": "CELL_A_1",
        "kpi_name": "kpi_2",
        "kpi_value": 25999.1796875,
        "anomaly": 1
    },
    {
        "level_0": 5,
        "index": 5,
        "site": "CELL_A",
        "time": "2022-09-15T09:30:00Z",
        "cell": "CELL_A_1",
        "kpi_name": "kpi_2",
        "kpi_value": 21172.47265625,
        "anomaly": 0
    },
    {
        "level_0": 6,
        "index": 6,
        "site": "CELL_A",
        "time": "2022-09-15T09:00:00Z",
        "cell": "CELL_A_1",
        "kpi_name": "kpi_3",
        "kpi_value": 14729.478515625,
        "anomaly": 0
    },
    {
        "level_0": 7,
        "index": 7,
        "site": "CELL_A",
        "time": "2022-09-15T09:15:00Z",
        "cell": "CELL_A_1",
        "kpi_name": "kpi_3",
        "kpi_value": 25999.1796875,
        "anomaly": 0
    },
    {
        "level_0": 8,
        "index": 8,
        "site": "CELL_A",
        "time": "2022-09-15T09:30:00Z",
        "cell": "CELL_A_1",
        "kpi_name": "kpi_3",
        "kpi_value": 21172.47265625,
        "anomaly": 1
    },
]
```

Each Site has a number of cells and KPI values.
I need a new object of Cells with if an anomaly was detected in the last object for that cell.

For example The above would become

```
[
    {
        "name": "CELL_A_1",
        "value": {
            "anomaly": 1,
            "kpi_names": [ "kpi_1", "kpi_3" ]
            "site": "CELL_A"
        }
    },
]
```

I tried map() but I just cannot get it doing what I need

```
let t = new map()
data.forEach((item) => {
    if (t.has(item.site)) {
        t.set(item.cell {
            site: item.site,
            kpi_name: item.kpi_name,
            anomaly: item.anomaly,
        })
        } else {
            t.set(item.site, {
            site: item.site,
            kpi_name: item.kpi_name,
            anomaly: item.anomaly,
        })
    }
})
return Array.from(t, ([name, value]) => ({
    name,
    value,
}))
```

Any help greatly appreciated as am under pressure in work :(

Comment: What's `t` in the above? What's `t.has`?

Comment: Where did you try `map()`? Not seeing in your code above. When you try that, what's the actual output vs expected output?

Comment: Why doesn't `kpi_2` also appear in the output? One of its objects has an anomaly of 1.

Comment: Fundamentally, you seem to want `const result = data.filter(/*...*/).map(/*...*/)`. Give it a go!

Comment: Apologies, code edited... t is a map(). Also KPI_2 is not included as the last object for its anomaly is 0, this ignoring the previous object which was 1

Comment: Per your code, `t.has(...)` will always be false because you don't populate `t`.